# How can I make these axes longer (to the end of the last tick)?

Tags: plotting, functions

please give solution if you vote to close.
Don't just not reading the post and judge yourself.

How can I make these axes longer (to the end of the last tick)?

The comment kind of works but what if I want to make them longer exactly same as the end of the last tick? Is there any way to do it other than manually trial and error?  
Another problem with the suggestion is that `PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]` remove the label `0`.

[image]

```
Show[Plot[x, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {0, 5}}], 
 Plot[x^2, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 5}}], 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.005], 12], 
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

From suggestion with `PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.01]` you can see that the label 0 is not there.
(13.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit))

```
Show[Plot[x, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {0, 5}}], 
 Plot[x^2, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 5}}], 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.005], 12], 
 GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.01]]
```

[image]

Comment: Just make your range more extra with 0.1 i think this is fast one avoiding complications!



Show[Plot[x, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  PlotRange -> {{-3.1, 3.1}, {0, 5.1}}], 
 Plot[x^2, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 3.1}, {0, 5.1}}], Axes -> True, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.005], 12], 
 GridLines -> Automatic]

Comment: Add the option `PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.03]` to the `Show`

Comment: Thanks, one problem with these suggestions is that the functions are plotted in the extended ranges as well which is undesired in this case.

Comment: `PlotRangePadding` doesn't extend the range of the function. To make this more obvious, look at `PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]`

Comment: @BobHanlon somehow it behaved weird when I first tested it but it works now. What if I want to make them longer exactly same as the end of the last tick? Is there any way to do it other than manually trial and error?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of

Comment: @BobHanlon `PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]` remove the label `0` for the x axis. How can I get it back?

Comment: Read the documentation. `PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[0.1], {Scaled[0.01], Scaled[0.1]}}`

Comment: @BobHanlon that doesn't help, the label 0 still not there.

Comment: With version `13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)` it is there. `Show[Plot[x, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {0, 5}}], Plot[x^2, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 5}}], AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.005], 12], GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[0.1], {Scaled[0.01], Scaled[0.1]}}]`

Comment: I'm using 13.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)  and it doesn't work.

Comment: It's funny that people only know vote to close without giving a solution.

Comment: Please show me why close and how to solve the problem I posted.

Comment: Simple mistake? Why? Why don't you just give a solution instead of just vote to close?